# Practical meaning of output in simple recurrent neural network

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to learn RNN model. Here is the model I built:

```py
N = 3 # number of samples
T = 10 # length of a single sample
D = 3 # number of features
K = 2 # number of output units
X = np.random.randn(N, T, D)

# Make an RNN
M = 5 # number of hidden units

i = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(T, D))
x = tf.keras.layers.SimpleRNN(M)(i)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(K)(x)

model = tf.keras.Model(i, x)

Yhat = model.predict(X[0].reshape(1, -1, D)) # output: array([[-0.67114466, -0.65754676]], dtype=float32)
```

I don't understand the meaning of `Yhat`. Here I consider X as sequential data:

`[data_point0...data_pointT], [data_point0...data_pointT], [data_point0...data_pointT]`

Each data point has `D=3`features.

Here `Yhat.shape==(1, 2)`.

2 doesn't equal to `D` which is a number of features. I guess, `model.predict()` doesn't make a prediction on the next data point. If `model.predict()` do prediction on the next data point, The shape of the result should be `(1, D)`.

Then what's the practical meaning of `Yhat`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pay attention to the model.

After the `RNN` layer you used a `Dense` layer where the output dimension is 2!
So the size of the output you get by running the `model.predict()` is fine.

If you wish it to have other dimensions alter the output size of the `Dense` layer. From `x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(K)(x)` to `x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(D)(x)`

The question if the model does/doesn't predict properly depend on multiple issues such as the training data, hyper-parameter etc.

Comment: If I set K = D, the shape of Yhat will be (1, 3), could I understand the result got from model.predicted() function represent the predicted value of the next data point?

Comment: @TianyiWang if all the training data was such to let the model predict the next data point then Yes